# Why the screen rotation on my Dell Latitude 7390 2-in-1 not working?

Tags: laptop, drivers, windows-11, dell-latitude, sensors

The screen rotation function in my laptop Dell Latitude 7390 2-in-1 is not working when the laptop is bent beyond 180 degrees. The keyboard stays on and is only turned off when the computer is bent completely.

I tried updating all my drivers and restoring the bios settings but the problem doesn't seem to be resolved.

Note that this feature works sometimes and others not, and sometimes the computer turns off when it's rotated.

I also tried reinstalling the integrated sensor solution but it didn't solve the issue.

Update: Apparently the reinstallation eventually helped, but not immediately, although I restarted the device multiple times the rotation feature only worked the next day and the problem was finally solved!!

Comment: Does this Dell KB article help? [No Auto Rotation on XPS 13 9365 and Latitude 7389 2-in-1 Systems](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-aw/000145205/no-auto-rotation-on-xps-13-9365-and-latitude-7389-2-in-1-systems#:~:text=In%20Settings%2C%20turn%20off%20%22Rotation,degrees%20transitioning%20to%20tablet%20mode.)

Comment: all drivers are up to date yet the problem persists

Comment: Read it again :-) What you are experiencing is clearly a known and documented issue, and the article is marked "Solution". It doesn't advise to update anything, but to **reinstall** the [Intel Integrated Sensor Solution Driver](https://dl.dell.com/FOLDER04417074M/8/Intel-Integrated-Sensor-Solution-Driver_7TH4D_WIN_3.10.100.3429_A00_05.EXE). Just that, nothing else. If that doesn't resolve it, I'd contact Dell support.

Comment: the integrated sensor solution is not compatible with my device according to dell

Comment: I probably linked wrong file. Go to your local Dell site. Under Support you can search for the exact model you have with the product ID.

Comment: Please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1767854/edit) your question to add new info like testing & results. That way everything relevant is easily available for the community members without digging through comment threads.

Comment: okay so I tried reinstalling it, still same problem

Comment: Has this device always behaved as you expected it to or is this a new issue?

Comment: a new issue, it was working perfectly fine, and suddenly started malfunctioning